# Multiple COUNT SELECTS from the multiple tables in single query

Tags: sql-server

I have different table 4 of them are site, job, notes and PO. Site is location and one site can have multiple jobs,  job can have multiple notes and POs, now i like to select all job on the basis of site number with the count of notes and POs in single query how can i do this with single query. I used this query but this shows the PO count only. Using SQL-Server DB

```
SELECT jobid, job_title, po_id, count(po.po_id) PO_count, count(notes) note_count
FROM notes
LEFT JOIN job ON jobid = notes_job_id
LEFT JOIN po ON po_job_id = job_id
LEFT JOIN site_detail ON site_id = _job_si_id
LEFT JOIN site_list ON sitelist_id  = site_sitelist_id
WHERE site_id = 116291
GROUP BY  jobid, job_title, po_id
```

Please help, Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select jobid, job_title, 
    (select count(po.po_id) from po where po.po_job_id=jobid) as PO_count,
    (select count(note.id) from notes where notes.notes_job_id=jobid) as note_count,
from job
where site_id = 116291
```

You should be able to use any number of 'subselect as column' patterns, to fetch the different counts. Another good thing about this is that it doesn't require restructuring your actual main query.

The column names & join structure aren't exact.. You'll have to fill in the gaps.

I found your DB & naming conventions unclear & rather poor. Why don't you use table names/aliases as qualifiers? This would mean you could name foreign-key columns the same in different tables, so joins would be very clear & obvious, rather than this ugly hack of prefixing them.

I'd design it very simply:

```
notes.FK_JOB      -> job.ID
po.FK_JOB         -> job.ID
site_jobs.FK_SITE -> site.ID
site_jobs.FK_JOB  -> job.ID
```

Isn't that easy & just so much simpler?

I also have no idea what a PO is, except that it is both prone to conflicts (with aliases, other columns, temporary names) and uninformative. Both due to it's extreme shortness.

Comment: PO is actually purchase order and its the table name

Comment: That's what I guessed might be possible.. If Order is ORDER, I'd suggest PurchaseOrder could be PORDER. "PO", as a super-short name, is extremely general & prominent in the namespace -- thus more likely to conflict (with aliases, other columns or temporary names). It's also less informative & clear than PORDER would be.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `count(distinct ...)` on the primary key of the table:

```
SELECT  jobid
,       job_title
,       count(distinct po.po_id) po_count
,       count(distinct site.site_id) site_count
,       count(distinct note.note_id) note_count
,       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would aggregate counts before join, I think this is most efficient way:

```
select
    j.jobid, j.job_title, po.po_count,
    ...
from job as j
    left outer join (
        select count(*) as po_count, po.po_job_id
        from po as po
        group by po.po_job_id
    ) as po on po.po_job_id = j.job_id
    ...
where j.site_id = 116291
```

BTW it's really hard to read query when you're not using `<table name>.<column name>` notation, I strongly recommend to use aliases for tables and use dot notation for all columns

Comment: Seconded on the `<alias>.<column name>` notation. Since he's trying to select Jobs with counts of (Job.Notes) and (Job.PurchaseOrders), wouldn't the counts as subqueries in the SELECT clause be simplest? That requires no joining or grouping, just subqueries.